# GWT Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I am running into a problem which is quite a bit surprising. I have an GWT application, which i can run perfectly fine on Firefox, but the same GWT application does not open up in Internet Explorer.

When using Firefox i use `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>` and when i want to run in Internet Explorer  i change it to `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8"/>`   and debug.This way i am sure that the problem i am having is not related to deferred binding.

When using the Internet Explorer (IE 8) i cannot even get into the onModuleLoad() part of my application.It looks as if Internet Explorer has downloaded all its stuff ,but has nothing to display.

Is there something that i am missing here

Comment: How are you embedding the application into your page?  Depending on how the javascript is loaded, I've had some issues with IE8 and 9 with regards to embedding inside div tags as well as doctypes in your page.

Comment: This is how its loaded.Is this what you wanted?
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
 src="home/home.nocache.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.The GWT plugin for IE crashed on my local machine.I re installed it before writing this question,but i was sucessful the second time.Donno the reason yet,but its working now.